$\beta$ and $\eta$ reduction rules
In type theory, certain reduction rules are classified as $\beta$-reduction rules and others are classified as $\eta$-reduction rules. What is the difference? Why are some rules called $\beta$-reduction rules and others $\eta$-reduction rules? Is there some important conceptual difference between these types of rules? I haven't been able to find any good discussions of this in the literature.

They are in a sense dual to each other: $\beta$-rules govern the behaviour of eliminators applied to constructors, while $\eta$-rules govern the behaviour of constructors applied to eliminators. See the nlab pages on conversion rules, beta-reduction and eta-conversion for more information.

Let's examine the case of products: a product of $A$ and $B$ is an object $A \times B$ with projections $\pi_1 : A \times B \to A$, $\pi_2 : A \times B \to B$ such that, for every object $C$ with morphisms $c_1 : C \to A$, $c_2 : C \to B$, there exists a unique morphism $\langle c_1, c_2 \rangle : C \to A \times B$ such that $\pi_1 \circ \langle c_1, c_2 \rangle = c_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ \langle c_1, c_2 \rangle = c_2$. You can view $\langle -, - \rangle$ as a generalised pair constructor that takes morphisms instead of elements. More generally, we think of constructors for a type as "maps into" the type, and of destructors as "maps out of" the type, so $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the destructors here.
The existence part here already gives us the $\beta$-rule, since it says what happens when you apply the destructors $\pi_i$ to the constructor $\langle -, - \rangle$. The uniqueness part gives the $\eta$-rule as follows: consider $\langle \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle$, the constructor applied to the pair of destructors. We have $\pi_1 \circ \mathrm{id}_{A \times B} = \pi_1$ and $\pi_2 \circ \mathrm{id}_{A \times B} = \pi_2$, so by uniqueness we also have $\langle \pi_1, \pi_2 \rangle = \mathrm{id}_{A \times B}$.
Now, the product $A \times B$ is equivalently defined as a representing object for the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-, A) \times \mathrm{Hom}(-, B)$: this means that we should have an isomorphism $$\varphi_C : \mathrm{Hom}(C, A) \times \mathrm{Hom}(C, B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(C, A \times B)$$ natural in $C$. In one direction, we have $\varphi_C(f, g) = \langle f, g \rangle$, and in the other we have $\varphi_C^{-1}(h) = (\pi_1 \circ h, \pi_2 \circ h)$.
We recover the $\beta$- and $\eta$-rules as the two sides of this isomorphism:

The $\beta$-rule says that $\varphi_C^{-1} \circ \varphi_C = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. $(\pi_1 \circ \langle f, g \rangle, \pi_2 \circ \langle f, g \rangle) = (f, g)$ for all pairs $(f, g)$.
The $\eta$-rule says that $\varphi_C \circ \varphi_C^{-1} = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. $\langle \pi_1 \circ h, \pi_2 \circ h \rangle = h$ for all $h$.


The situation with coproducts is formally dual: we write $[f, g]$ for the unique morphism $A + B \to C$ induced by $f : A \to C$ and $g : B \to C$ such that $[f, g] \circ \iota_1 = f$ and $[f, g] \circ \iota_2 = g$. In programming languages, $[f, g](x)$ would often be written something like $\mathrm{case}\ x\ \mathrm{of}\ x_1. f(x_1); x_2. f(x_2)$. Here $[-, -]$ plays the role of the destructor while $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ play the role of the constructors.
Similarly, the coproduct $A + B$ is a representing object for the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -) \times \mathrm{Hom}(B, -)$, so we have an isomorphism $$\psi_C : \mathrm{Hom}(A, C) \times \mathrm{Hom}(B, C) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(A + B, C)$$ natural in $C$. In one direction, we have $\psi_C(f, g) = [f, g]$, and in the other we have $\psi_C^{-1}(h) = (h \circ \iota_1, h \circ \iota_2)$.

The $\beta$-rule says that $\psi_C^{-1} \circ \psi_C = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. $([ f, g ] \circ \iota_1, [f, g] \circ \iota_2) = (f, g)$ for all pairs $(f, g)$.
The $\eta$-rule says that $\psi_C \circ \psi_C^{-1} = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. $[h \circ \iota_1, h \circ \iota_2] = h$ for all $h$.


This seems a little unclear in the case of sum types. There, $\beta$-reduction is used to simply terms of the form case[inL($x$),[$u$]$c$,[$v$]$d$] or case[inR($x$),[$u$]$c$,[$v$]$d$]. I see how these are eliminators applied to constructors. But $\eta$-reduction applies to terms of the form case[$t$, [$u$]$s$(inL($u$)), [$v$]$s$(inR($v$))]. That doesn't look to me like a constructor applied to an eliminator.

You have to open your mind a bit and accept a somewhat generalised notion of constructor and destructor. To make sense of this formally, you should look at the definition of products and coproducts (sums) in category theory in terms of universal properties. There, $\beta$-rules correspond to the existence part of the universal property while $\eta$-rules correspond to the uniqueness part (this is why they are also called "uniqueness rules").

Universal properties can be rephrased in terms of isomorphisms (this is the representability perspective), which makes it clearer that $\beta$- and $\eta$-rules are dual: they correspond to the $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}$ and $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$ conditions in an isomorphism.

Do you know of a good text that discusses the connection between $\beta$-rules, $\eta$-rules, and the relevant category theory? I have some basic knowledge of category theory and universal properties, so just something explaining the connection with $\beta$- and $\eta$-rules would be sufficient.

No but I've added a small write-up to my answer, hope it helps.
